# Numbering of multiple line equation and page break

Tags: amsmath, page-breaking

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand*\d{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}}
\allowdisplaybreak

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \left| \int_YT(\chi_{A_j})\chi_{B_k}\d\nu \right| &\leq \int_Y\left| T(\chi_{A_j})\chi_{B_k}\right|\d\nu\nonumber\\
    &= \left\|T(\chi_{A_j})\chi_{B_k}\right\|_{L^1}\nonumber\\
    &\leq \left\|T(\chi_{A_j})\right\|_{L^{q_0}} \left\|\chi_{B_k}\right\|_{L^{q_0'}}\\
    &\leq M_0\left\|\chi_{A_j}\right\|_{L^{p_0}} \left\|\chi_{B_k}\right\|_{L^{q_0'}}\nonumber\\
    &\leq M_0 \mu\left(A_j\right)^{1/p_0}\nu\left(B_k\right)^{1/q_0'}\nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to prevent adding `\nonumber` manually in each line and still getting a pagebreak? I can get such a numbering with `equation` and `split` or `aligned` but then no pagebreak is possible since those environments generate a block.

Comment: What about using `align*` (which is similar to issuing `\nonumber` at every line) with a `\tag` to set the numbering for a specific line, and issuing `\allowdisplaybreak` in your preamble (to allow breaking across the page boundary)? Hmmm... what about that?

Comment: This will be at least confusing. In case you absolutely need a page break in the middle of the display, use `subequations` and add a number to each line.

Comment: @Werner Sorry, forgot the `\allowdisplaybreak`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breaking such a display across pages should be the very last resort. Just one number will however be confusing, either if it falls at the bottom of a page or at the top of the next one.

In case you absolutely need a page break, you can use `subequations` to have a number next to each line, thus helping the reader to know the display is really a single one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} % DON'T redefine \d

\textheight=5cm % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{subequations}\label{test}
\begin{align}
\left| \int_YT(\chi_{A_j})\chi_{B_k}\diff\nu \right|
  &\leq \int_Y \lvert T(\chi_{A_j})\chi_{B_k} \rvert \diff\nu
\\
  &=    \lVert T(\chi_{A_j})\chi_{B_k}\rVert_{L^1}
\\
  &\leq \lVert T(\chi_{A_j})\rVert_{L^{q_0}} \lVert \chi_{B_k} \rVert_{L^{q_0'}}
\displaybreak\\
  &\leq M_0\lVert \chi_{A_j}\rVert_{L^{p_0}} \lVert \chi_{B_k}\rVert_{L^{q_0'}}
\\
  &\leq M_0 \mu(A_j)^{1/p_0}\nu(B_k)^{1/q_0'}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I removed all useless `\left` and `\right`, changing most of them to the better `\lVert` and `\rVert`.

Also I recommend you not to redefine `\d`. You'll know why when your bibliography will contain some Hindi or Arabic name.

(I have used a reduced text height just for easier production of the example.)

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks. The reason for asking this is that I currently write a seminar report for university and the resulting equations are usually long, but sometimes it is necessary to refer to them using a number. However, if I let them in a ''stiff'' block like `aligned`,  then underfilled pages are the result. I think another way of solving this would be to put the number on the first or last line of the block. What do you think about this? Maybe this would have been a better question to ask initially.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek It would be confusing anyway. However, you need `\nonumber`, for that.